# converting a simple sh script to the equivalent batch script on windows

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, bash, batch

This is the script that I need to convert to batch file in windows :

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

TOOLS=./build/tools

$TOOLS/caffe train \
    --solver=examples/cifar10/cifar10_full_relu_solver_bn.prototxt
```

this is the script I came up with so far:

```
REM go to the caffe root
cd ../../Build/x64/Release
caffe.exe train --solver=../../../examples/cifar10/cifar10_full_relu_solver_bn.prototxt

pause
```

This executes the executable (`caffe.exe`) and passes the needed argument file as needed, but the problem is the argument file itself is pointing to another file which is relative to itself, and this second file is not found.
This is how the second file inside our argument file addressed :

```
net: "examples/cifar10/cifar10_full_relu_train_test_bn.prototxt"
```

To make things more clear, the hierarchy of the folders is like this :

```
|Build 
   |--X64
      |--Release
         |--caffe.exe
|Examples
   |--Cifar10
      |-- cifar10_full_relu_solver_bn.prototxt
      |-- Cifar10_train_test.prototxt
      |-- other files as well
```

my question is, Is  there a way that I can use so that I dont need to change all relative file addresses as well ?

Comment: Put `caffe.exe` in your path. In the batch file `cd examples`.

Comment: its not applicable at the moment, both folders contain lots of stuff.

Comment: Thanks but Its not applicable at the moment, I try some other methods and see if I can get it in the way I intend

Comment: Why did you delete your answer containing your solution?

Comment: @DavidPostill, I noticed NOLFXceptMe has already posted the answer, although not completely correct, I thought its a good Idea to accept his answer and then apply the needed correction to it and make perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET TOOLS=Build/x64/Release
%TOOLS%/caffe.exe train --solver=examples/cifar10/cifar10_full_relu_solver_bn.prototxt

pause
```

That should be the ideal conversion of the shell script. We always stay at the root folder, so paths inside the file provided as an argument should be referenced correctly.

Comment: yes thanks, but you are missing a `cd ../../` command the very beginning or otherwise this wont work.

Comment: Your shell script should be at the top folder. Placing it inside `Build/x64/Release` is a bad practice.

Comment: why is it bad practice ?

Comment: by the way I'd be grateful if you could add this notice that, this script should be executed from the root or otherwise it wont work(if called from the sub directory where the actual bat file resides).

Comment: by the way there is slight problem here, When I run this script from the root sth like this ( T:\Git\CaffeRoot> data\mnist\get_mnist_data.bat`
the files are not save inside the mnist folder, they are saved in the root folder which is wrong! How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution is duplicating the entire Cifar10 folder to the proper location.

Comment: not a practical solution at all. but thanks anyway

Comment: I don't know the logic of this program. I thought if it doesn't matter where the second (text) file is located then one can copy this file to the location where the program expects it to be just to make it accessible. If it does matter then this isn't the case.

Comment: actually, the folders contain lots of stuff and moving them around is not logical at all, thats why I asked this in first place, in linux I have no problem, everything works as expected, but on windows i was abit off till I figured it out just now :) 
Thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

### **Update :**

Here is a note, this script is for when you want to execute a batch file by lets say double clicking on it directly. (I mean execute the batch file directly from the (sub)directory inwhich it resides.
but if you intend on either calling it from the root of your folders, you need to see the accepted answer. I leave my answer here aswell, in case it may come in handy for some others.

### Actual Answer

I myself am using the standard method which is accepted as the answer.
Thanks to dear God, I finally Got it working, the actual equivalent batch script is as follows:

```
REM go to the caffe root
cd ../../

set BIN=build/x64/Release

"%BIN%/caffe.exe" train --solver=examples/cifar10/cifar10_full_relu_solver_bn.prototxt

pause
```

using this, I no longer need to change anything.